# Mongoose node return multiple arrays of referenced objects from document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on a node backend API with mongoose. I have 2 schemas one User schema and one Follow schema(saved as users and follows in mongo). The follow schema fields followers and following hold an array of ObjectIds that refer to User objects. I am trying to return the Referenced objects in in the arrays so that I can respond with an object to the client that contains an array of userFollowing and userFollowers containing user objects, a but I am unable to populate the output.

I will also need to be able to filter the returned objects to only return `'username bio image email first_name surname join_date'`.

My current incorrect output is below. I am not sure if its an error in my query or if I am using the correct approach.

> [ { _id: 5c7dc1b92f3f1dd8ad9df993,
>       user: 5c7d93b57a29ce05a096c492,
>       userFollowing: [],
>       userFollowers: [] } ]

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var FollowSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  followers: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  following: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } }
);
 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Follow', FollowSchema);
```

```js
// username must be unique and is required
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  join_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Tell me about yourself'
  },
  image:{
    type: String,
    default: 'profile.jpg'
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }

});
```

```js
User.findOne({
    'username': username
  }, function (err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({
        'state': false,
        'msg': `No user found with username ${username}`
      })
    } else {
      const user_id = user._id;
      Follow.aggregate([{
          $match: {
            "user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user_id)
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            "from": "follows",
            "localField": "following",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "userFollowing"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            "from": "follows",
            "localField": "followers",
            "foreignField": "_id",

            "as": "userFollowers"
          }
        }, {
          $project: {
            "user": 1,
            "userFollowers": 1,
            "userFollowing": 1
          }
        }
      ]).exec(function (err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        res.json({
          'state': true,
          'msg': 'Follow list',
          'doc': doc
        })
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: The `from` field should be `"users"` since that is the collection you are "joining to". With mongoose you can use `User.collection.name` to avoid confusion with the actual collection names assigned by the models.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you. Originally was using "user" but User.collection.name did the trick. How would I go about filtering the output to basically adapt `User.find({
    username: req.params.id
  }).lean().select('username bio image email first_name surname join_date').exec(function (err, user) {
    res.json(user);
  });` to work with lookup?